# How to convert the main content of a web page into a pdf file?

Tags: pdf, webpage

I have a long web page of a study guide, I want to convert the main content of that page into pdf, I mean minus the navigation bar, the footer, and so on. Is there a tool to do that? I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and my main browser is Firefox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a web page into a PDF?](http://superuser.com/questions/381871/how-to-convert-a-web-page-into-a-pdf)

Comment: I think it's not a dup; the other question and answers are tailored to making the entire page searchable and this is about 1) extracting a relevant part of the page for 2) conversion to PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the Firefox add-in Web2PDF for that purpose if the web page is generally clean.  If there is a lot of stuff I don't want to include, I use another add-on, Print Edit, which lets you delete anything you don't want printed.

EDIT:  I always just use the Add-on Manager; search on the name or function.  However, based on the comment, I noticed external links:
http://www.web2pdfconvert.com/pdf-button
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-edit/

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you added links to the addins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mobilizer such as the one from readability, as detailed in [this Q/A from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961509/readability-in-my-application).  Here's an example of what the page would look like (copied from the SO answer): http://www.readability.com/m?url=http://www.cnn.com/2013/01/11/showbiz/tv/golden-globes-tv-vineyard/index.html?hpt=hp_abar

All you have to do is edit the above link to substitute the URL you want "cleaned" for the CNN example.

Then you can use your favorite pdf utility (such as [Web2PDF](http://www.web2pdfconvert.com), mentioned in another answer here).

Answer (score 0):

If you were on Google Chrome, I would say that you can use Print option in menu and choose "Save as PDF" as your printer.

But for now, you can use PrintFriendly web site to easily convert your online web page to a PDF file.

http://www.printfriendly.com

Edit: There is also another way: You can save the web page as an HTML file, edit with a WYSIWYG editor and after editing convert it with an HTML2PDF or PDF Printer or any other tool you know!

Comment: I tried it now, it doesn't hide the sidebars.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed You can remove everything in PrintFriendly with just clicking on it :D

Answer (score 0):

A solution which is a bit manual but does not require installing anything or using any third-party services:

Copy-paste the text from browser to LibreOffice Writer, then choose File - Export as PDF. If you copy carefully you can even avoid copying the header, footer and other elements you don't need.

Easy! :)